# How to group flights in timetable by day of week?

Tags: mysql, sql

That's my table called "flights":

```
| ORIGIN | DESTINATION | DAY_OF_WEEK | DEPARTURE_HOUR | FLIGHT_NUMBER | AIRLINE     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   FRA  |    MAD      |      1      |                |               | Lufthansa   |
|   FRA  |    MAD      |      3      |                |               | Lufthansa   |
|   FRA  |    MAD      |      6      |                |               | Lufthansa   |
|   LHR  |    MUC      |      1      |                |               | Lufthansa   |
|   LHR  |    MUC      |      2      |                |               | Alitalia    |
|   JFK  |    EWR      |      5      |                |               | Delta       |
|   BCN  |    MAD      |      7      |                |               | Ryanair     |
|   FRA  |    MAD      |      7      |                |               | Lufthansa   |
|   FRA  |    MAD      |      1      |                |               | Iberia      |
```

The question is, how to get timetable grouped by origin, destination, airline and day of week, like this:

```
FRA -> MAD 1*3**6*7 Lufthansa
FRA -> MAD 1******* Iberia
LHR -> MUC 12****** Alitalia
JFK -> EWR ****5*** Delta
BCN -> MAD *******7 Ryanair
```

My current query is: `SELECT origin, destination, airline FROM flights GROUP BY origin, destination, airline ORDER BY origin;` but as you can see, it doesn't return days of week formated like `1*3*567`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to `pivot` your results.  You can do this with `MAX` and `CASE`:

```
select origin, destination, airline,
  max(case when day_of_week = 1 then '1' else '*' end) as `1`,
  max(case when day_of_week = 2 then '2' else '*' end) as `2`,
  max(case when day_of_week = 3 then '3' else '*' end) as `3`,
  max(case when day_of_week = 4 then '4' else '*' end) as `4`,
  max(case when day_of_week = 5 then '5' else '*' end) as `5`,
  max(case when day_of_week = 6 then '6' else '*' end) as `6`,
  max(case when day_of_week = 7 then '7' else '*' end) as `7`
from flights
group by origin, destination, airline
order by origin;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7cc0d/2)

It wasn't clear if these should be a single column or not -- I left them separated, but easy enough to `concat` together.